# There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Select district. Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected

Tags: flutter, dropdown, provider

I keep getting a dropdown errors, There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Select district. Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected.

If I change something get another one. API is working fine and data is added to the list. everything works but this one didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your each `DropdownMenuItem<String>` you have to also provide `value:` argument, this argument has to be different on each `DropdownMenuItem` and one of them has to be equal to `DropdownButtonFormField<String>` `value:`

As an example:

```dart
final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> ll = [
  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
    value: '1',
    child: Text('1'),
  ),
  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
    value: '2',
    child: Text('2'),
  ),
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
    value: '1',
    items: ll,
    onChanged: (value) => print(value),
  );
}
```